# In EF Code-first approach always need to re-deploy other application connected to same database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have multiple projects in one solution and I am only using one DBContext since I only have single database for all. I have deployed those applications and they are now stable. However, one of the project need to add a single column, then after changes made and migration to DB has been done, some of the projects got an error (Model Backing). I need to update the .dll of all those application just to make it updated. I always do the same whenever there are enhancement or changes in one of my application.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to deploy it whenever there is some db change as you are using code first approach.
Another way could be to disable automatic migration for all other projects which you don't want to redeploy.